# What is this woman saying?

Tags: meaning, listening

I cannot get what she says in the audio track:

> http://s9.picofile.com/d/8351599092/2f362c97-d44d-4aa7-acfb-f1503cbb7d9c/Untitled_01.m4a

How can I understand such a quick speaking, in general?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for a transcription, and unlikely to be helpful to future users, and does not provide any indication of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the woman is saying:

> Good. I was hoping you'd come up with it.

The only way I know of that can help you develop your ability to process authentically-spoken English in real time is practice. Listen to English everyday. The trick is that you have to be constantly exposed to the language.